# How to validate input type text feild as input type time

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to validate the text field as a time input. in the text field, I want to show hours and minutes like this.
ex: 12:25

I am already trying some codes.

```js
function changetrigger(inputField){
  var isValid = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(inputField.value);

  if (isValid) {
     console.log('Success');
  } else {
     console.log('Unsuccess');
  }

  return isValid;     
};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
   <div>Starting Time</div>
   <input type="text" onchange="changetrigger(this);" id="morning" ng-model="main.morning_r" placeholder="00:00">
</div>
```

When I run this code error occurred in the console.
"changetrigger is not defined".

I am new to code. can u help me to fix this or another way to do this validation?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. From the snippet above, the code works as it should.

Comment: I do get the error aswell when trying the code

Comment: @Patrick You get the `changetrigger is not defined` error by running the snippet right here in the OP's question?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No i dont get the error here on SO, but I get it if I try the code elsewhere.

Comment: @Patrick Then you must have some other issue as the code is extremely simple and, as you can see here, it works just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, since both OP and I have this problem, and I can recreate the problem by directly copying the code and testing it somewhere else (https://jsfiddle.net/rbmo02gk/), it would suggest that there is a problem with the code.

Comment: @Patrick, so looking into your fiddle, the function is being initialized after the element is loaded into DOM, jQuery has $ready function to detect the DOM load and then declare function, But in case of JS, you need to put the function inside HEAD or before the input field with a script tag.

Comment: You didn't set up your Fiddle properly by setting the JS to be in the HEAD. Once you correct your Fiddle configuration, it works (https://jsfiddle.net/Lwozq91p/2/) Since the the code right here in the question (the OPs code) doesn't produce the error, I'd say the problem is with something else.

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui which then could be the solve for OP

Comment: @Patrick yeah, find below my answer in detail (cc: R.Minod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate hours/minutes, you can use regex like:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$

//If you're going to allow one digit in the minutes go with:
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])$
```

It will be better to attach the event in your code like the sample below.

**NOTE:** Using the `input` event is the most efficient way to track the user inputs.

```js
function changetrigger() {
  var isValid = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$$/.test(this.value);

  if (isValid) {
    console.log('Success');
  } else {
    console.log('Unsuccess');
  }

  return isValid;
};

document.getElementById('morning').addEventListener('input', changetrigger);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <div>Starting Time</div>
  <input type="text" id="morning" ng-model="main.morning_r" placeholder="00:00">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`ng-model` in your HTML suggests that you are using AngularJS then why not you use `ng-keyup` / `ng-change` and declare a scope function in controller ? It is better to use this all in angular way.

```
//Example
$scope.changetrigger = function() {
     // your logic here
}
```

Another option is using `ng-pattern` that can be used with regex.

**JAVASCRIPT way:**

> Please Note: If you are trying to mix Javascript with AngularJS then do > not forget to put below `changetrigger` function inside HTML file's
>   head/script tag OR before the input field so that it initialize before 
>   DOM becomes ready. Primafacie, it looks like you have declared that
>   function in controller class and in result it is `not defined` or the 
>   function is declared after the element in HTML file

1- I used `onkeyup` instead of `onchange` (for demo)

2- I do also change your regex to /\d{2}:\d{2}/

```js
function changetrigger(inputField){

     var isValid = /\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(inputField.value);

     if (isValid) {
         console.log('Success');
     } else {
         console.log('Unsuccess');
     }

     return isValid;     
 };
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
     <div>Starting Time</div>
     <input type="text" onkeyup="changetrigger(this);" id="morning" placeholder="00:00">
 </div>
```

Comment: `onchange` is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: @ScottMarcus and DownVoters:  `onchange` will trigger only after focus-out and as much as I can understand, he need to check the time format continuosaly. May be he will decorate box accordingly.

Comment: He does not need to check the input continuously because it will fail validation upon each keystroke until the full pattern is entered. Checking after the focus is lost (change) is appropriate. But, beyond that, which event he uses doesn't have anything to do with the question about the error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok man ! I have updated my answer with many things.

Comment: But your answer still doesn't address the actual question, which was about an error message for the function not being found.

Comment: Yeah, I guess he has declared that function inside AngularJS controller and trying to access that from that input field. Let me put that also in answer. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus DONE, is it now acceptable at some level ? :-)

Comment: No, because the problem has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: May be, but suggesting for better is always good. He is using angular so just not mixing-up will be better approach.

Comment: The question here wasn't "How can I make this code better?" Your entire "answer" doesn't address the question being asked and so it's not an "answer". The OPs code actually works just fine as it is. The problem is most likely that the Fiddle environment wasn't configured properly.

Comment: You must read again. This is not about mixing JS with Angular. Angular has nothing to do with this issue. Since the problem is just a simple mis-configuration of the Fiddle where the code is being run, the question should be closed with only a comment needed to explain the issue.

Comment: I guess we have wasted a lot of time on a question where OP is 100% silent. Let move on and wait when he comes back on it. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i was trying to add ur code @BilalSiddiqui but in the console i get an error "changetrigger is not defined". how to fix dat. sorry for ur time i am new to coding.

Comment: @R.Minod can you post your file here ?

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui i think i already fix this problem thank you very much. i was use onchange function and it work fine. again thank u guys :)

Comment: @R.Minod if this answer was helpful to you ? then accept it and mark the question closed. Otherwise, if the solution is something different, add an answer and accept that one. Happy to see you out of problem :)

Answer (score -2):

Check this (remeber to include jquery with this)

Jquery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
```

```js
$('.inputField').on('change', function(){
    
     var isValid = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$$/.test($('.inputField').val());
    
      if (isValid) {
         console.log('Success');
      } else {
         console.log('Unsuccess');
      }
    
      return isValid;  
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <div>Starting Time</div>
  <input type="text" class="inputField" id="morning" ng-model="main.morning_r" placeholder="00:00">
</div>
```

This will eliminate the problem of the function "not being defined".

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery.

Comment: He writes he is new to code. Maybe he doesn't know this is an option, but now he does. Always good to inform of multiple ways to solve the problem, so he can make an informed decision on which way to go.

Comment: It's actually not a good idea to answer a question with technologies that the question was not tagged with. Since the OP is new to code, adding a library just makes it more confusing. Instead, a simple comment mentioning alternatives is more appropriate. Additionally, JQuery is advocated way too often to solve simple problems that vanilla JavaScript and the standard DOM are well-equipped to solve without 3rd party libraries.